# Which method between db.createIndex() and db.createIndexes() is more preferred for creating multiple indexes in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, performance, indexing, query-optimization, pymongo

There are two methods of creating indexes: db.createIndex() and db.createIndexes() .

- db.createIndex() example in pymongo: 
  `>>> db.create_index([("hello", DESCENDING),("world", ASCENDING)])`
  `>>> db.create_index([("goodbye", DESCENDING)])`
- db.createIndexes() example in pymongo:
  `>>> index1 = IndexModel([("hello", DESCENDING),("world", ASCENDING)])`
  `>>> index2 = IndexModel([("goodbye", DESCENDING)])`
  `>>> db.test.create_indexes([index1, index2])`

Which is better and why?